# How can I define a function computed in a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a Carathéodory function $b:\Omega\times R\to R$ and a singular measure $u_0$. I need to define a composition $b(x,u_0)$, can I consider the composition of $b(x,\cdot)$ with $u_0$, i.e., $b(x,u_0)$, as a singular measure? I'm note sure. I'm not a math expert so apologies if this is a trivial question.

Comment: It's hard to understand this question. You define $b$ as having three arguments but then write "$b(x,u)$". Presumably $T$ is a positive real number and $R$ is the real line, but what is $\Omega$? What are you even trying to do, define the composition of a function with a measure? Why do you "need" to do this?

Comment: It's corrected, $\Omega$ is a bounded domain of $R^N$. In order to deal with generalized porous medium problems with measure initial data  of the form $b(x,u_0)$. The result is true when $u_0$ is integrable, in this case $b(x,u_0)$ is also integrable but in case of measures I need first to define this composition.

Comment: To make it clearer is it possible to give a concrete example?

Comment: For example, the model example $b(x,u)_t-\Delta_p u=f\in L^{1}(Q)$ in $(0,T)\times \Omega$ with $b(x,u)(0)=b(x,u_0)$ in $\Omega$. Here $u_0$ is a singular measure and $b(x,s)$  is a Carathéodory function such that the derivatives $b_{s}(x,s)$ and $\nabla_{x}b(x,s)$ are also Carathéodory functions.

Comment: In this case $b(x,u_0)$ is also a Radon measure? that is, can I consider a decomposition $(b(x,u_0)^r,b(x,u_0)^s)$ (the absolutely continuous and the singulars parts) of $b(x,u_0)$? or I should use the the decomposition of the form $(b(x,u_0^r), b(x,u_0^s)$)?

Answer (score 1):

I add an answer to my question: If $u_{0}$ is a singular measure then
$$
b(x,u_{0}):=b(x,u_{0}^{r})+\nabla_{x}b(x,\infty)u_{0}^{s}
$$ is a well defined measure, this composition with measures is well established at least for $b(s)$ having a linear behavior at infinity, say whenever $b'(s)$ has a finite limit, i.e.,
$$
b'(\infty)=\underset{s\to \infty}{\text{lim}}b'(s).
$$
In that case the composition works like follows: for $u_{0}=u_{0}^{r}+u_{0}^{s}$ with $u_{0}^{r}$ is the Lebesgue part in $L^{1}(\Omega)$ and $u_{0}^{s}$ its singular part, then
$$
b(u_{0})=b(u_{0}^{r})+b'(\infty)u_{0}^{s}
$$
(other cases where discussed by using the recession function of $b$ at infinity), for details see the works of G. Buttazzo in the frameworks of calculus of variations functionals (the case $b(x,u_{0})$ is done accordingly as it is done for Carathéodory functions).